# Error during compilation of sql embedded in a COBOL program

Tags: sql, db2, cobol, mainframe, zos

I have trying to insert user-inputted data into a table "C01371" using COBOL and SQL in a mainframe server. I am getting an error of "Unused or undeclared host variable 'quantity'" despite the fact that I already declared it and used it too. I tried to learn more about the host variables and embedded SQL programs in cobol. But so far I couldn't find a solution. Please help me rectify my error. Thanking You all.

Declaration:
[image]

Cobol Code:
[image]

Error during compilation:
[image]

Comment: Perhaps you should use data type PIC S9(9) COMP. instead of integer?

Comment: Get the sample COBOL programs working in your environment, and pay attention to https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPEK_12.0.0/apsg/src/tpc/db2z_equivalentcoboldatatypes.html

Comment: Thank you for the help. It worked.